# Celery-Redis worker showing weird results on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask, redis, celery

I have built a Flask application which I have hosted on Heroku, Celery as the worker with Redis as the Broker and for saving the backend on Redis itself, has the following code:

```
def create_csv_group(orgi,mx):
    # Write a csv file with filename 'group'
    cols = []
    maxx = int(mx)+1
    cols.append(['SID','First','Last','Email'])
    for i in range(0,int(mx)):
        cols.append(['SID'+str(i),'First'+str(i),'Last'+str(i),'Email'+ str(i)])
    with open(os.path.join('uploads/','groupfile_t.csv'), 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for i in range(len(max(cols, key=len))):
            writer.writerow([(c[i] if i<len(c) else '') for c in cols])


@app.route('/mark',methods=['POST'])
def mark():
    task = create_csv_group.apply_async(args=[orig,mx])
    tsk_id = task.id
```

If I try to access the variable tsk_id, sometimes it gives the error:

variable used before being initialized.

I thought the reason it was not sending the task to the queue before I was accessing the tsk_id. So I moved the function after two form filling pages.

But now, it is not updating/saving the file correctly, it shows weird output in the file(Seems to be the old file data, which should get updated on filling the new form). When I run the same code locally, it runs perfectly fine. I logged the worker, it goes in the task function, runs properly too.

Why is this weird output is being displayed? How can I fix both of the issues, so that it writes properly to the file and check on the task id?